# XCode: Where are sqlite files copied from when app is installed on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sqlite

I recently tested my iPhone app on my iPhone versus the simulator. Since I first created and added my sqlite file I have made structural changes to the database. The only way I can figure out how to update the changes to other simulators is to actually paste the version I modified into the Application directories.

This is fine for the simulators but I don't know where XCode gets the sqlite file when it pushes it to a device. Where is this so I can replace the file? Alternatively, is there another way to update the sqlite file that XCode uses for new devices? (I have already tried importing new version into my project).

Update: I removed an older version of my SQLite DB from my project, and added a newer version. I cleaned, rebuilt, but the iPhone is still using an older version of the database.
[image: Here is the db file in the project navigator]

Comment: As I'm aware you should just execute insertion and update. It'll save changes automatically (or when you closed it?).

Comment: If you you include the database in your app's bundle, it's automatically included when the user installs the new app. You should not be messing around with navigating around the file system of the simulators: That's entirely unnecessary. Just run/install the new app, and it's there. The only question is what you've done in your app code. (E.g. usually we have SQLite databases for updates as the user runs the app, at which point we copy it from the bundle to Documents and open it there.) You have to show us how you're opening/creating SQL databases. Also, you're not using Core Data, right?

Comment: @Rob if by "include the database in your app's bundle" you mean add the sqlite file to my project, then I have done that. I even deleted the old .sql file and added the new one, but the version it is putting on my test device is the old file.  
When you update your SQLite DB for an update, how do you update it in the XCode project? I used sqlite3 in the terminal to add a column to a table, but only to one of the simulators as I am unclear how to make the change propagate to all the simulators and devices I am testing on.

Comment: Assuming this isn't some simple confusion between copies of the database in the Documents folder and the bundle, I have admittedly encountered problems where Xcode has gotten confused about files edited outside Xcode and those files not getting properly updated on a build. (This happened a long time ago and I assumed this bug had long since been fixed.) Anyway, when I had that problem, I found the derived data folder, quit Xcode, deleted the contents of the derived data folder, and restarted Xcode and it worked again. You might want to try that.

Comment: So when you make changes to the DB do you always do it programatically? I guess I could try that..

I don't really understand what you mean by "bundle".. is that just the files that are part of my project? Also, is there a derived data folder for actual physical devices that is on my development computer? Thanks.

Comment: @Rob I deleted the app on my phone and re-ran... now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.. I needed to reload the correct database file in my project, then delete the app on my phone. Then it worked with the correct database the next time I ran the app on my phone.